# How to get a pixel color from a specific sprite on touch (unity)?

Tags: unity, 2d, color, pixel

I have a 2 layers of a different sprites. How can i get a pixel color from lower sprite?

I know how to get touch and world coordinates, but i have no idea what to do next.

```
Touch touch0 = Input.GetTouch(0); // screen touch coordinates
Vector2 playerPick = GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(touch0.position); // world coordinate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sample image data for my color picker utility.  Raycasting will effectively return all objects that were clicked on, regardless if they appear underneath another one.

[image]

So first, you need to extract the image color data.

```
Color[] Data;
SpriteRenderer SpriteRenderer;

public int Width { get { return SpriteRenderer.sprite.texture.width; } }
public int Height { get { return SpriteRenderer.sprite.texture.height; } 

void Awake()
{
    // Get renderer you want to probe
    SpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();       

    // extract color data
    Data = SpriteRenderer.sprite.texture.GetPixels();
}
```

Then on Touch or MouseDown, you would determine if the click is inside of your image (via a collider and raycast) and then determine what pixel you clicked on inside of your image:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {

    // Get Mouse position - convert to world position
    Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);    
    screenPos = new Vector2(screenPos.x, screenPos.y);

    // Check if we clicked on our object
    RaycastHit2D[] ray = Physics2D.RaycastAll(screenPos, Vector2.zero, 0.01f);
    for (int i = 0; i < ray.Length; i++)
    {
        // You will want to tag the image you want to lookup
        if (ray[i].collider.tag == "TAGNAME")
        { 
            // Set click position to the gameobject area
            screenPos -= ray[i].collider.gameObject.transform.position;
            int x = (int)(screenPos.x * Width);
            int y = (int)(screenPos.y * Height) + Height;

            // Get color data
            if (x > 0 && x < Width && y > 0 && y < Height)
            {
                Color = Data[y * Width + x];
            }                   
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My picker is opened sourced, so if you want to further investigate this, check out https://github.com/jongallant/UnityColorPicker

Comment: Is there any way to get pixel color without any second-sided extension? May be i don't understand something. I do have to use it, right?

Comment: No, god no.  You can implement this yourself.  The code above is all you need.  I can try to better explain in a little bit.

Comment: I don't know why, but this function does not came in to 'for' cycle.

Comment: Do you have any idea what exactly may be wrong? I have camera, sprite and text on my scene, but RaycastHit2D length is 0.

Comment: Does your sprite gameObject have a collider attached to it?

Comment: Does your sprite gameObject have a collider attached to it?   You will need to have one in order for the raycast to work.  I updated the answer a bit to clarify how this works.

Comment: Almost everything works correct now, except SpriteRenderer. `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Comment: You need to actually hook it into the SpriteRenderer component that your image is using.  This is completely reliant on your scene.

Comment: I am really sorry for that question, but how can i do this?

Comment: Depends on how you have it setup, however, if you attach the script to the same GameObject as your image -- you can literally just do GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>() and it should work.  Otherwise, I would need to know more about your scene setup.  Can you join the GDSE Chatroom?

Comment: This is just a test setup. I have camera with attachet script (this script control camera zoom/moving etc). Sprite is right under the camera. http://i.imgur.com/uXVxlnh.jpg

I understand that this is a very bad, but this is my first time using unity and i have to make what i am doing rly fast. I will do everything correct later on, after showing this result.

I can't come to chat since my reputation is 1.

Comment: Attach the script to the same object as your image.

Comment: I attached script directly to the sprite. Somehow i havenumbers like -2809523 | -548380 (x and y). `int x = (int)(screenPos.x * Width); int y = (int)(screenPos.y * Height) + Height;`

Comment: What you should do, is download that color picker -- then study how it works.  And try to reproduce it yourself in your application.  Add me on skype if you have questions @jgallantgames